# Logisim - wire holds value 'e' when zoomed out, but not when zoomed in

Tags: digital-logic, simulation

I'm trying to make a multiplier in logisim. This is a full picture of my schematic:[image]

As you can see, there is an 'e' coming out of my 'XXXXX-XXX00' adder. But, when I look at the schematic for 'XXXXX-XXX00' adder, this is what I see:

[image]

Why am I getting 'e' outside of the adder but not inside of it? How can I get it to output the 'right' value?

Also - this one wire isn't the only place I'm getting these 'e's. Depending on the values of the 2 numbers I'm multiplying, I'll get these 'e's in all sorts of fun places.

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: What other kinds of places are you getting the Es? Sounds like a bug to me, I can't think of any logical reason for that to happen. Maybe file bug report?

Comment: @Tim The majority of them are coming out of the final adder, but sometimes they're coming out of the other adders as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a bug. I ran the same *.circ* file on another computer and got no problems.